# Traversing HTML: how can I hide a color when I move to another element?

Tags: jquery, css, dom

When I move to a new element in my document, it gets painted and that is OK. But when I leave that element I need it to clear that color and should follow the color button. How can I do that? Thanks for any help!

Here's a link for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/9TPtn/10/

HTML code:

```
<ul>ul1
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li class="point_me">3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
<ul>ul2
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>

<br/>

<div>
    <p id="Pr"><button>Prev</button></p>
    <p id="Ne"><button>next</button></p>
    <p id="Si"><button>siblings</button></p>
    <p id="Ch"><button>children</button></p>
    <p id="Pa"><button>parent</button></p>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
div, li {
    width:40px; height:40px; margin:10px;
    float:left; border:2px blue solid; 
    padding:2px;
}

ul {
    width:100px; height:10px; margin:10px;
    float:left; border:2px blue solid; 
    padding:2px;
}

span {
    font-size:14px;
}

p {
    clear:left; margin:10px
}​
```

jQuery code:

```
var $elm = $(".point_me");
$elm.css("background", "#cac");

$("#Pr").click(function() {
    $elm = $elm.prev();
    $("div").css("background", "");
    $elm.css("background", "#cac");
});

$("#Ne").click(function() {
    $elm = $elm.next();
    $("div").css("background", "");
    $elm.css("background", "#cac");
});

$("#Si").click(function() {
    $elm = $elm.siblings();
    $("div").css("background", "");
    $elm.css("background", "#cac");
});

$("#Pa").click(function() {
    $elm = $elm.parent();
    $("div").css("background", "");
    $elm.css("background", "#cac");
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Please describe your question better.

Is this what you wanted?

http://jsfiddle.net/9TPtn/11/

```
function resetColor(){
    $('li').css("background","transparent");
}
```